# How to use Enumerate with Variable data properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use enumerate with data in a variable but the variable data is getting enumerated
as a single string how can i use in the below format

Excepted output comes when i use with statement :

```
with open("sample.txt") as file:
    for num, line in enumerate(file):
        print(num, line)

output

0 sdasd
1 adad
2 adadf
```

but when

```
data = "adklkahdjsa saljdahsd \nsjdksd"
for num, line in enumerate(data):
    print(num, line)

output

0 a
1 d
2 k
3 l
4 k
5 a
6 h
7 d
8 j
9 s
10 a
11  
12 s ... so on
```

Comment: You see that string is not a file and behaves differently. You will have to split the string on a line break (`\n`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enumerate expects an iterable. In your example it takes the string as iterable an iterates over each character.

It seems what you want is to iterate over each word in the text. Then you first need to split the string into words.

Example:

```
data.split(' ') # split by whitespace
```

Full Example:

```
data = "adklkahdjsa saljdahsd \nsjdksd"
for num, line in enumerate(data.split(' ')):
    print(num, line)
```

Comment: using Klaus suggestions of splitlines did the trick thanks